# How to set data correctly in localstorage?

Tags: angular

When I try to select an **address** from the list using a **radio** button and save to **localstorage** I get **null** as a result.

How to fix it?

**html**:

```
   <form [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group formControlName="pickup_points_id">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let pickuppoint of pickuppoints">
          <ion-label>{{pickuppoint.address}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" [value]="pickuppoint.pickup_point_id" (click)="onSelectPickupPoint()"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

**ts**:

```
 onSelectPickupPoint() {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedPickupPoint', this.form.value.pickup_points_id);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('selectedPickupPoint'))
  }
```

Comment: try to put the code of the `onSelectPickupPoint` in a `setTimeout(() => {})` just to make sure the event of the click is handled properly before saving the value. The rest of your code looks fine. Another thing could be the initialization of the `this.form` field

Comment: @bvdb Hmm. and if you setTimeout, then everything works.

Comment: @bvdb Maybe can somehow get rid of setTimeout?

Comment: try the `(change)` event. I think it's called after the event has been processed, actually modifying the form. But it's a bit unpredictable, because it slightly depends on the type of form-element. Also, I think the `(change)` event is sometimes called multiple times, e.g. when losing focus after editing an input field. Which may not be an issue in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value isn't processed yet. The `(click)` event fires just **before** the form has been updated. This actually gives you control on the event. *For example, it gives you the ability to cancel the event. (e.g. by passing the `$event` to the function in your template code and calling the `e.stopPropagation()` method).*

So if you execute the code with a `setTimeout` it will actually be fixed, because the event will first be processed. That allows it to update the form with the new value. Finally when the timeout is processed the `this.form.value.pickup_points_id` will hold the correct value.

Another solution may be to use the `(change)` event instead, which will be fired **after** the value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(click)="onSelectPickupPoint($event.target.value)"
```

.ts:

```
onSelectPickupPoint(point_id: number) {
  localStorage.setItem('selectedPickupPoint', point_id);
}
```

It works for text input. try it on radio and see.